# Is there a way to sculpt without affecting edge length?

Tags: sculpting, brushes

Essentially I want to be able to 'grab' without *stretching* as the Grab brush does.

For example, when I use the grab brush to move the mesh, it lengthens the edges. I want to keep them the same, just moving the vertices.

[image: For example, when I use the grab brush to move the mesh, it lengthens the edges. I want to keep them the same, just moving the vertices.]

Comment: i don't know how to say it, but just think about this: imagine you have two vertices, one edge in between. The only way to move one vertex without changing the length of the edge is moving that vertex along a sphere around the other vertex. And this is true for all (!) edges and their corresponding vertices if they should move as you want. So sorry but mathematics has a problem with your kind of prerequisition and i am sure this is not the kind of deformation you want. And furthermore i would say: sculpting without changing edge length makes less sense.

Comment: but maybe you just want to rotate some piece of mesh, where all vertices are in one line and you want to rotate around that line, then it would be possible.

Comment: For example, how would I form a half-circle with the mesh I have here without extending any edges. Maybe that makes more sense?